# Hiding only div content using javascript not the picture and border of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide only the div content not the div border and image and width of the div. The code is below:

```
<div>
    <img src="image.jpg">
        1
    </img>
</div>
```

And this div also contains border and picture. I just want to hide 1 in the div. How can I achieve it using javascript?

Comment: <div><img>1</img></div> and this div also contains border

Comment: Wrap the content in its own tag, and hide only that tag.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; `img` elements do not have a closing tag, and do not contain other data.

Comment: You can hide all the chidren, but you will need to wrap the items you want hidden in a div or container - see http://plnkr.co/edit/9Uzir5j8HbU2MjBRxQHj?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Ok, your HTML is invalid to start with, as image tags don't have closing tags. So, let's pretend this is what you have now:

```
<div>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    1
</div>
```

All you need to do is wrap your content you want to hide in another `DIV` or `SPAN`, which will allow you to reference it easily later on. So:

```
<div>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div id="contentToHide">1</div>
</div>
```

And with some jQuery, you can hide it easily like this:

```
$('#contentToHide').hide();
```

Or, with pure Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('contentToHide').style.display = 'none';
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tztj2yuf/)**

Comment: the div tag is like:     <div id="contentToHide">    <img src="image.jpg">1
</div>

Comment: i want to hide 1 but not the image

Comment: @Ali - the method I have provided you hides the 1 but not the image!

Comment: @Ali: please see this working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tztj2yuf/